# multiplying real part of a complex number while imaginary part stay tact (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I am trying to multiply real part of a complex number to a scalar while the imaginary part stay the same.

For example `x= a + bi`  after multiplying to `c` result us `y= ca + bi`.

Any suggestions on procedure?

Comment: `y=real(x)*c+imag(x)`?

Comment: Nope. didn't worked.
`h = 1 + 2i`
>> `y=real(h)*2+imag(h)`

`y =

     4`

Comment: As in my answer, don't forget to multiply imag(x) with 'i' !

Comment: Are you sure?
I tried but it is not giving me the correct form I wrote in question.

Comment: Yes I am sure: `h = 1 + 2 * i` >> `y = real(h) * 2 + imag(h) * i` (<- do not forget the i here) results in `y = 2 + 2 * i`

Comment: Yes. Thank you. my code made me wrong on this.
It's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use the `real` and `imag` functions in MatLab. So the multiplication becomes:

```
y = real(x) * c + imag(x)*i
```

`real`(see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/real.html)) retrieves `a` from `x` and `imag`(see [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/imag.html)) retrieves `b` from `x`. Don't forget to multiply with `i` again ;)